# Can't create keyboard shortcuts utilizing the `Esc` key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, system-settings

In Ubuntu I used to be able to go to `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts` and set a shortcut such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, but that no longer seems to be the case in Ubuntu 20.04. Any shortcut involving the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key doesn't seem to work. I imagine this is because the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is used to cancel the shortcut entry routine @ `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Is there a manual way to define keyboard shortcuts in the terminal, or some other way to assign a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: You want super+esc as a short cut rite.. Esc alone should do its own job.. am I rite?

Comment: @PRATAP that is correct, I want `Super+Esc` as the shortcut. But I can't even enter `Super+Esc` as a shortcut option through the `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts` dialogue. Presumably because this combination includes `Esc`. I used to be able to do this on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Super+Esc combo is already give out of the box.. Just disable that and you are good to go.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIbar.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination you are looking for is a default keyboard shortcut for "Restore the keyboard shortcuts"

[image]

Disable it first to use the combination for your custom keyboard shortcut.

[image]

[image]

Comment: good answer. Unfortunate that "super escape" resets everything (i think?), whereas the near-neighbor "alt-escape" is a default shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

To add a keyboard shortcut that is disallowed by the sanity checking in the GUI, add via the command-line instead. See "https://techwiser.com/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu/".

Check first for an already existing custom list:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
```

If the list doesn't already exist, then create one:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
```

Then add your shortcut:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "'my_new_shortcut'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "'<Super><Esc>'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "'<path/thing to execute>'"
```